# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages ,I get this error when I try to install livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Im using laravel 8 and my php version 8.0.12 for details check the photo

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IkNI.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your software dependencies have an incompatible version conflict.

Try to Run this command:

> composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

or

> composer update --ignore-platform-reqs